# Java replace multiplet characters using regular expression

Tags: java, spring, string, java-8

I am trying to write a String replace method , it works but looks bad using multiple replace methods on same string. Pretty sure I could use a regular expression here.

```
        List<String>  strng = Collections.singletonList(answer.toString()
                .replace(",", "/")
                .replace("#"", " ")
                .replace("*", "")
                .replace("&", "")
                .replace("]", ""));
```

I would like to use just 1 replace() or replaceAll() method.
in short trying to construct a Regular expression to replace these  characters  **,  #  *  &  ]**

Comment: I don't think it looks bad ..

Comment: @akuzminykh thanks but  trying to improvise  and minimize duplicate code :) .

Comment: If you wanted to replace them with the same thing, it would suit using a regular expression. But if you're replacing them with different things, you're better off with multiple method calls.

Comment: @icecool09 *FYI:* I think it's fine. Just because you call the same method multiple times it's not "bad" duplication. Bad is to have e.g. two times 10 lines of identical code (relative). I think your code here is very clear and doesn't require the reader to understand regex, which is good for readability and maintainability. Of course doing regex here is the big-brain-style code but IMO it won't be a true improvement.

Comment: ahh thats true . @akuzminykh

Comment: I've written this line before, and what you have in the OP is preferable IMO. I recommend leaving it explicit and each replace separate.  A regex will make it much harder to maintain code and you're not getting much (if anything) in return for that.

Comment: why not use a natural language processing library if you're trying to process some text. they have all the lower level tools https://haifengl.github.io/nlp.html

Answer (score 1):

Simple regex replacement operations do not support conditional replacements in one operation.

With a recent JDK and “preview-features” enabled, you could do as

```java
static final Pattern SPECIAL_CHARS = Pattern.compile("[,#*&\\]]");
```

```java
List<String> strng = List.of(
    SPECIAL_CHARS.matcher(answer.toString())
        .replaceAll(mr -> switch(mr.group().charAt(0)) {
            case ',' -> "/";
            case '#' -> " ";
            default -> "";
        }));
```

A Java 8 compatible equivalent would be more elaborated:

```java
static String replaceSpecialChars(String input) {
    Matcher m = SPECIAL_CHARS.matcher(input);
    if(!m.find()) return input;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(input.length());
    do {
        String s;
        switch(m.group().charAt(0)) {
            case ',': s = "/"; break;
            case '#': s = " "; break;
            default: s = "";
        }
        m.appendReplacement(sb, s);
    } while(m.find());
    return m.appendTail(sb).toString();
}
```

While these approaches perform the operation in one go, you’d need a really large input string to draw a benefit from that. Otherwise, your chain of plain (non-regex) `replace` calls is likely to be more efficient. You could even replace the first two from `String` to `char` replacements, i.e. `.replace(',', '/').replace('#', ' ')`. Since the other three have the same replacement, they could get replaced by a single `.replaceAll("[*&\\]]", "")` but as said, using the regex engine is not necessarily more efficient than multiple plain text replacement operations.

Answer (score 0):

The last three calls can be replaced with one call by using regex as shown below:

```
List<String>  strng = Collections.singletonList(answer.toString()
                .replace(",", "/")
                .replace("#", " ")
                .replaceAll("[\\*&\\]]", ""));
```

The regex, `[\\*&\\]]` specifies any of `*`, `&` or `]`. Learn more about character classes from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html).

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hello,Hi#Bye*World&Welcome]Good";
        System.out.println(str
                            .replace(",", "/")
                            .replace("#", " ")
                            .replaceAll("[\\*&\\]]", ""));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello/Hi ByeWorldWelcomeGood
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use the Apache Commons library you can use the method [replaceChars](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceChars-java.lang.String-char-char-)

```
replaceChars(String str, String searchChars, String replaceChars)
```

from the StringUtils class. But just because of the one method to include the library would be superfluous in my opinion.

```
String str = "foobar,123#xyz*abc&def]";
String res = StringUtils.replaceChars(str, ",#*&]", "/ ");
System.out.println(res);

//output : foobar/123 xyzabcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide it into two parts.

1. Remove all the characters (replacement with an empty string (`""`). Use  `String::replaceAll` with a Regex defining a set of characters to be removed: `answer.replaceAll("[*&\\]]", "")`.
2. Have two strings ready containing the characters *before* replacement and *after*. Enforce the same length of both strings and a rule that each character is subsituted with exactly *one* another (according to your question). You can use `String[]` for this purpose. Iterate through the characters and replace them in the original string.

```
String[] mapping = {",#", "  "};

// The advantage is the code below remains the same regardles the number or replacements
String newAnswer = IntStream.range(0, mapping[0].length()).boxed().reduce(
    answer.replaceAll("[*&\\]]", ""),
    (str, i) -> str.replace(mapping[0].charAt(i), mapping[1].charAt(i)),
    (l, r) -> l);
```

As you can see, `IntStream.range(int, int)` comes handy. Moreover, you can use the removal result  itself as an `identity` of the reduce operation.

---

**Disclaimer:** The solution is suitable only for a large set of characters to be removed to avoid repetitions. Otherwise a chain of `String::replace` is more than suitable.

Comment: Good points! I have fixed these flaws: `str[1]` really should be `mapping[1]` and `*` should also not be there as long as it is removed first and never mapped. `String::concat` was a result of a forgotten copy-paste mistake from the experiments I had been doing. Thanks for leaving a comment!

Comment: But `(l, r) -> l` isn’t a correct combiner either. It would discard the replacements made at the right-hand part. I think, something like `(l,r) -> { throw new UnupportedOperationException(); }` would be better. If you want to bring in `reduce` at all costs, you could use `String newAnswer = IntStream.range(0, mapping[0].length())  .<Function<String,String>>mapToObj(i -> s -> s.replace(mapping[0].charAt(i), mapping[1].charAt(i))).reduce(s -> s.replaceAll( 


"[*&\\]]", ""), Function::andThen) 
 .apply(answer);`